# How to add event listener to call hangup PHP AGI?

Tags: asterisk, agi, phpagi

I am working on a project that records how long a caller is on the line.

My question is, how do you add an event listener for hangup with AMI or AGI?

Currently, I am trying to use AGI's Manager class however the event is not firing when the call is terminated.

```
$Log_File = "/var/www/html/admin/modules/timetracker/agi-bin/Log.txt";

function CallHungUp($e,$ch=NULL,$u=NULL,$ca=NULL)
{
    file_put_contents( $Log_File,"HANGUP E - " . implode(' ',$e),FILE_APPEND);
}

$asm = new AGI_AsteriskManager();
if($asm->connect("localhost","Secret","Info"))
{
    $asm->add_event_handler('Hangup','CallHungUp');
}
else
{
    file_put_contents( $Log_File,"UNABLE TO CONNECT TO ASM",FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possible way

1) use h-extension

2) check SIGKILL event

3) check CHANNEL(status) after long action.

Comment: Where can I find documentation for these methods?

Comment: In every asterisk book?

Comment: As an expert what books would you suggest to a complete novice, such as myself?

Comment: ORelly's "Asterisk the future of telephony"